# some elastislide images fail to load in IE9

Tags: image, internet-explorer-9, elastislide

I'm using 2 elastisliders on a web page and everything works fine in firefox, chrome, safari, ie8 and 10 but in ie9 some images fail to load. The images which are failing to load are random (a page refresh results in different images failing to load). When I left-click and select "show image" the image appears just fine. I already added a image loading script written for IE specific but this doesn't seem to help. anyone?